# Confused as to how infinate ajax scroll works in retrieving other posts

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

So I am new to javascript and struggle a bit to understand it, especially in conjunction with html.  None the less, I decided to give the infinite ajax scroll a try. Here is how my javascript looks:

```
var ias = jQuery.ias({
        container:  '#container',
        item:       '.item',
        pagination: '#pagination',
        next:       '.next'
    });


    ias.extension(new IASSpinnerExtension());

    ias.extension(new IASNoneLeftExtension({html: '<div class="end-text"><p><em>Pat yourself on the back, you\'ve reached the end!</em></p></div>'}));
```

But I am confused on the html a bit. Specifically on the pagination part.

```
<div id="container">
  <div class="item">here is one!</div>
  <div class="item">here is two!</div>
</div>

<div id="pagination">
  <a href="page2.html" class="next">2</a>
  <a href="page3.html" class="next">3</a>
  <a href="page4.html" class="next">4</a>
</div>
```

I understand that the first container is what loads initially. When you scroll to the end of the content, the next page should load which is a separate html document. But when I try this code out and scroll down, it is only loading the last page in the html (page4.html in this case). What am I doing wrong? Am I not understanding something properly? I apologize for the stupid question but any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I guess you should have assigned the class `.next` to only one of your links :

```
<div id="container">
  <div class="item">here is one!</div>
  <div class="item">here is two!</div>
</div>

<div id="pagination">
  <a href="page2.html" class="next">2</a>
  <a href="page3.html">3</a>
  <a href="page4.html">4</a>
</div>
```

Because your plugin seems to be looking for the link with the class `.next`.

But you had three of them.